# How to combine p-cancelable and p-progress npm packages to get a cancelable progress reporting promise

Tags: javascript, promise, progress, cancellation

I would like to have a cancelable promise that reports progress at the same time. Something like a combination of [p-progress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-progress) and [p-cancelable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-cancelable). And while usage of any of them separately is simple I'm struggling a bit to combine them both.

This is what I tried so far which successfully reports progress but throws `cancelablePromise.cancel is not a function` error.

```js
import PCancelable from 'p-cancelable';
import PProgress  from 'p-progress';

const cancelablePromise = doJobWithProgress();

try {
    cancelablePromise.onProgress((progress) => {
        console.log('progress: ' + progress);
    });

    await sleep(500);

    cancelablePromise.cancel();

    const result = await cancelablePromise;

    console.log("result", result);
}
catch (error) {
    console.log("Main catch error: " + error);
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

function doJobWithProgress() {
    return PProgress((progressCallback) => {
        return new PCancelable((resolve, reject, onCancel) => {
            try {
                let progress = 0;

                const interval = setInterval(() => {
                    progress += 0.1;
                    progressCallback(progress);
                }, 100);

                const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    const result = 1;
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    resolve(result);
                }, 1000);
    
                onCancel(() => {
                    console.log('canceled');
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    clearInterval(interval);
                });
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log('Promise catch error: ' + error);
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: And this, kids, is why you should not subclass `Promise`. Progress reporting and cancellation should be separate channels, not be part of the promise.

Comment: I don't really see how troubles in combining two separate libraries is an argument against inheriting the `Promise` @Bergi

Comment: @Bergi, I did some research and I agree that for cancellation purpose it would be better to use `AbortController` but still, I don't see anything obscure in enriching `Promise` with `onProgress` event. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: One should not inherit from `Promise` to enrich it because subclassing is not composable with other enrichments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this complete - I ended up, as @Bergi suggested, with a different approach i.e., using `AbortController` and extending the `EventEmitter` class (I'm coding in NodeJS - for the web you can inherit `EventTarget`).

Maybe someone will be interested in answer to the original question - when trying to combine the two libraries I ended up creating a new `CancelableProgressPromise` class and copy-pasting the most necessary parts from the `p-progress` library to it and extending the `PCancelable`:

```js
import PCancelable from "p-cancelable";

export default class CancelableProgressPromise extends PCancelable {
    constructor(executor) {
        const setProgress = progress => {
            if (progress > 1 || progress < 0) {
                throw new TypeError('The progress percentage should be a number between 0 and 1');
            }

            (async () => {
                // We wait for the next microtask tick so `super` is called before we use `this`
                await Promise.resolve();

                // Note: we don't really have guarantees over
                // the order in which async operations are evaluated,
                // so if we get an out-of-order progress, we'll just discard it.
                if (progress <= this._progress) {
                    return;
                }

                this._progress = progress;

                for (const listener of this._listeners) {
                    listener(progress);
                }
            })();
        };

        super((resolve, reject, onCancel) => {
            executor(
                value => {
                    setProgress(1);
                    resolve(value);
                },
                reject,
                onCancel,
                progress => {
                    if (progress !== 1) {
                        setProgress(progress);
                    }
                },
            );
        });

        this._listeners = new Set();
        this._setProgress = setProgress;
        this._progress = 0;
    }

    get progress() {
        return this._progress;
    }

    onProgress(callback) {
        if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
            throw new TypeError(`Expected a \`Function\`, got \`${typeof callback}\``);
        }

        this._listeners.add(callback);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```js
import CancelableProgressPromise from './cancelableProgressPromise.js';

const progressablePromise = doJobWithProgress();

try {
    progressablePromise.onProgress((progress) => {
        console.log('progress: ' + progress);
    });

    await sleep(500);

    progressablePromise.cancel();

    const result = await progressablePromise;

    console.log("result", result);
}
catch (error) {
    console.log("Main catch error: " + error);
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

function doJobWithProgress() {
    return new CancelableProgressPromise((resolve, reject, onCancel, progressCallback) => {
        try {
            let progress = 0;

            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                progress += 0.1;
                progressCallback(progress);
            }, 100);

            const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                const result = 1;

                clearTimeout(timeout);
                clearInterval(interval);

                resolve(result);
            }, 1000);

            onCancel(() => {
                console.log('canceled');
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                clearInterval(interval);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}

// Output:
// progress: 0.1
// progress: 0.2
// progress: 0.30000000000000004
// progress: 0.4
// canceled
// Main catch error: CancelError: Promise was canceled
```